# Web2py built-in authentication, after filling in the username, email, etc it generates the following ticket

Tags: python, postgresql, web2py

I am new to web2py, when I came around to use the built-in authentication, after filling in the username, email, etc it generates the following ticket. 
I am a clueless to what to do! Any help would be really welcomed! 
I am running a mac osx 10.8. Postgres 9.3.

The ticket

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/JoaoBtte/Documents/python/Hello/gluon/restricted.py", line 217, in      restricted
     exec ccode in environment
  File "/Users/JoaoBtte/Documents/python/Hello/applications/Cifra/controllers/default.py",  line 90, in <module>
  File "/Users/JoaoBtte/Documents/python/Hello/gluon/globals.py", line 378, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "/Users/JoaoBtte/Documents/python/Hello/applications/Cifra/controllers/default.py", line 88, in user
    return dict(form=auth())
  File "/Users/JoaoBtte/Documents/python/Hello/gluon/tools.py", line 1297, in __call__
    return getattr(self, args[0])()
  File "/Users/JoaoBtte/Documents/python/Hello/gluon/tools.py", line 2554, in register
    self.login_user(user)
  File "/Users/JoaoBtte/Documents/python/Hello/gluon/tools.py", line 1976, in login_user
    user = Row(user)
  File "/Users/JoaoBtte/Documents/python/Hello/gluon/dal.py", line 6986, in <lambda>
     __init__ = lambda self,*args,**kwargs: self.__dict__.update(*args,**kwargs)
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the following line in one of your model files (usually in db.py) ?

```
from gluon.tools import Auth
auth = Auth(db)
```

Could you show us your default.py controller?